# shiro security hasPermission in micronaut

Tags: micronaut

Comming from old-grails-based knowledge, I'm currently trying to make friends with micronaut.

The first question I have, is there a "plugin" or something that let me use the permission-based security - like or with - apache-shiro?

Something like @HasPermission("customer:create") as an annotation for methods or classes?

Answer (score 1):

> The first question I have, is there a "plugin" or something that let
> me use the permission-based security - like or with - apache-shiro?
>
> Something like @HasPermission("customer:create") as an annotation for
> methods or classes?

Micronaut Security (https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/) is the de-facto standard for permission based security in a Micronaut service.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit confused by "roles". Is it correct that I would retun in the AuthenticationProvider with "UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails((String) authenticationRequest.getIdentity(), ['customer:show', 'customer:edit', 'customer:create', 'customer:update', ...])"?

Comment: "Is it correct that I would retun in the AuthenticationProvider with..." - What you would do in your own `AuthenticationProvider`, or even whether or not you should have your own, depends on an understanding of what your security requirements are.

Comment: The original question is asking if there is a permission based security library for Micronaut.  If you are asking a specific question about how to use the library, you should update the question or post a new question.